# One line, three variables

Tags: python

I am here trying to just make a simple calculator in python, and I wonder if its possible to make the 3 first lines in to one line when command run. What I mean with that is; I don't have to press enter to type the next number/operator but press space instead (in the input section).

```
while True:
    import operator

    num1 = int(input("Whats the first number:"))
    oper = input("Which operator would you like to use: (+,-,/,*,**,^)  :")
    num2 = int(input("Whats the second number:"))


    if oper == "+":
        x = operator.add

    elif oper == "-":
        x = operator.sub

    elif oper == "*":
        x = operator.mul

    elif oper == "/":
        x = operator.__truediv__
    elif oper == "**":
        x = operator.pow
    elif oper == "^":
        x = operator.xor

    else:
        print("invalid input")

    print(num1,oper,num2,"=",x(num1,num2))
```

Comment: Your writing is fine, by the way, other than those lower-case "I" pronouns but, since 14 year-olds seem to do that world-wide, we can let it go :-)

Comment: Your user can enter an arbitrarily complex string in response to the input() function.  You could parse that input to accept, for example, "3 + 4".  But now you're entering into the area of parser writing.  Writing a calculator parser is a common introduction to compiler design, so you're in just the right place.

Comment: Hi @Stian, welcome to StackOverflow! You can use a single `input` like `3 x 8` and simply use `cmd_parts = someinput.strip().split()`, `cmd_parts[0]` now contains the value `3`, you get the point...

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `split` method of Python strings to accomplish this. Note that this code depends on three objects, separated by spaces, being entered. If more or fewer are entered or the spaces are forgotten, or either "number" is not actually an integer, there will be an error.

```
print("Enter a number, a space, an operator, a space, and another number.")
num1str, oper, num2str = input().split()
num1, num2 = int(num1str), int(num2str)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rory's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54612285/797495) answer and comments pointed on the right direction, but here's a practical example:

```
operators = ["+","-","/","*","**","^"]
msg = f"Example query: 8 * 4\nAllowed operators: {', '.join(operators)}\nType your query and press enter:\n"

x = input(msg)
cmd_parts = [y.strip() for y in x.split()] # handles multiple spaces between commands

while len(cmd_parts) != 3: # check if lenght of cmd_parts is 3
    x = input(msg)
    cmd_parts = [y.strip() for y in x.split()]

# verification of command parts
while not cmd_parts[0].isdigit() or not cmd_parts[2].isdigit() or cmd_parts[1] not in operators :
    x = input(msg)
    cmd_parts = [y.strip() for y in x.split()]

num1 = cmd_parts[0]
oper = cmd_parts[1]
num2 = cmd_parts[2]

res = eval(f"{num1} {oper} {num2}")
print(num1,oper,num2,"=", res)
```

---

[Python Example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Ynd) (Enable **Interactive mode**)

Answer (score 0):

```
calc=input("type here:- ").split()
# type belove with space between
num1,operatoe,num2=calc[:]
# if length of calc doesn't equal to three you can continue with while loop 
print(num1,operator,num2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

An improved working calculator which handles some errors based on other answers:

```
import operator

x = {
        "+": operator.add,
        "-": operator.sub,
        "*": operator.mul,
        "/": operator.__truediv__,
        "**": operator.pow,
        "^": operator.xor
    }

while True:
    print("Enter a number, a space, an operator, a space, and another number.")
    try:
        num1str, oper, num2str = input().split()
        num1, num2 = int(num1str), int(num2str)
        print(num1,oper,num2,"=",x[oper](num1,num2))
    except:
       print("invalid input")
```